# How to get frame of UITableViewHeaderFooter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I would like to get the frame of displayed UITableViewHeaderFooter views, but unfortunately

```
[self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:i]
```

returns the correct UITableViewHeaderFooter based on its textLabel, but the frame is all zeroes:

> Printing description of header: <LUXViewTableSectionHeader:
> 0x7fc03de477f0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0;
> 0 0); text = ' ▽  Permissions'; tintColor = <UIDynamicProviderColor:
> 0x60000042dde0; provider = <**NSMallocBlock**: 0x600000af3d20>>;
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000a45ce0>; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x60000043c0e0>>

I can get valid frames for UITableViewCells, but not the headers and footers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive not laid out header view, try to use instead `UITableView` methods:

```
    open func rectForHeader(inSection section: Int) -> CGRect

    open func rectForFooter(inSection section: Int) -> CGRect
```